# Change spell check word separator

Tags: spell-checking

I want to change the characters, spell checking considers to being separating words.

I already have the following line in my `~/.vimrc` file, which makes `w` and `b` recognize words with a `-` in between as one word:

```
 autocmd BufEnter,BufNewFile,TabEnter *.md set iskeyword=38,42,43,45,47-57,60-62,_,@
```

According to ASCII the 45 is the `-` character. However, spell checking seems to use another list of characters. When I write something like:

```
abc-def
```

I want it to be considered one word only, so that I may add this word to my word list as a correct word, instead of one of the parts `abc` or `def` being marked as a spelling mistake.

Is this possible? If it is, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you can't do this, see [`:h spell.txt`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/spell.txt.html) (emphasis mine):

> WORDS
>
> **Vim uses a fixed method to recognize a word**.  This is independent of
>   `'iskeyword'`, so that it also works in help files and for languages that
>   include characters like `'-'` in `'iskeyword'`.  The word characters do depend on `'encoding'`.

Comment: Seems you're right, the second paragraph is also important:

> `The table with word characters is stored in the main .spl file. Therefore it matters what the current locale is when generating it! A .add.spl file does not contain a word table though.`

So one cannot change it in a self created extra file either it seems. I guess I could change the original German `spl` file.